# Administrator account on Ubuntu 18.04 machine

Tags: java, eclipse

How to be an adminstrator? How to save the file? It will not let me save it there.

```
"As an administrator create a new file called /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop using any text editor eg."
```

taken from the Install eclipse instructions:
https://linuxconfig.org/eclipse-ide-for-c-c-developers-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04

I cannot save this file with my one and only account that I am greeted to on the logon screen:

Is there more accounts?

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-beginners-guide/

Comment: well, there should be root. To to anything out of your home directory you should use (at least) "sudo". (that means super user do). So to create a file there (which is empty) you could do something like `sudo touch /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` - but that wont' help you. You have to fill that desktop file. Better copy an existing one - also using `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `vi` but you can use another text editor:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/   
sudo vi eclipse.desktop
```

Comment: thanks bloozguy... are you a player a player or listener?